# Stop/disable specific webservice under Apache

Tags: java, linux, jboss

I have jBoss running on Linux that runs a Java SOAP webservice.  I normally deal with none of those on a day-to-day basis, so can't give many specifics.  The webservice is a heartbeat for another part of the system.  Given the design of the system (which we are going to be changing soon, hopefully), we cannot take the server "out of rotation" to patch it.  What I'm wondering is there a specific way to disable only the webservice running the heartbeat while allowing the other web stuff to continue?

Comment: Not without all the details of the implementation there isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it lives in its own `.war`, remove the `.war` from `$tomcat_home/webapps` - the service will come down (and the rest will stay up).

Comment: So it turns out they're in the same war.  Would removing the .class file that handles the request be sufficient, or is that just a bad idea?

Comment: You cannot stop one piece of functionality in the webapp (the service that handles heartbeat requests) without affecting the other parts of the webapp *unless someone built that logic into the application themselves*

Comment: If it's jboss it definitely supports hot undeployment. Just remove the service form the jbosshome/server/myserver/deploy directory

Comment: The 2 services (1 to stop and 1 not to stop) are in the same .war, so I can't just remove the war.  Can I remove the .class file from the .war, or is that a bad idea?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you cannot touch the WAR and there's no easy way to stop a single service in a WAR without un-deploying it or a code change. This is a bit of a shot in the dark, but you might be able to separately deploy a [Tomcat Valve](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/Valve.html) at the container level which intercepts http requests bound for (i.e. matching the URI) the heartbeat web service. When you want to re-enable the heartbeat, you un-deploy the valve.

It doesn't stop the heartbeat, but you can stop it from getting requests.

Answer (score 0):

If there is any load balancer in the front, you might be able to temporarily block requests at that level.  Or if minor code changes are possible, you could introduce a new property in properties-service.xml (BLACKOUT_PERIOD_ACTIVE or something), and have you web service check it before responding.  If the blackout period is active, you can plug-in logic accordingly.